# Display two data fields' content in dropdownlist then hide one on clicking

Tags: c#, asp.net, selecteditem, dropdownbox

So what I want to do is when you click the dropdown it shows two items from the dropdownlist. Left side will show the ID and the right side will show the text.

So will look like (98739 | Smoker) then when you click onto the item you want the dropdown list will only show "Smoker"

I have tried

```
 string sqlGetClass = "select [code], [SnoMedCode] + ' | ' + [Descrip] as [fullDescrip] from LT__SmokingStatus";
        SqlCommand cmdSmoke = new SqlCommand(sqlGetClass, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSmoke);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlSmokeStat.DataSource = ds;
        ddlSmokeStat.DataTextField = "fullDescrip";
        ddlSmokeStat.DataValueField = "Code";
        ddlSmokeStat.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```

That works fine and it shows (98739 | Smoker) in the dropdown. But was wondering anyway of hiding the 98739 code from there after I have selected the item. I know I am setting it and calling that. So any other way to combine them to do as I wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I've made some editing to the title to clarify the task (you are not hiding other items in the list, but just a part of selected item).

Based on that assumption, the most straightforward solution would be re-query the same control with modified select SQL statement like: `"select [code], [Descrip] from LT__SmokingStatus"` and correspondingly modify the `DataTextField` binding like: `ddlSmokeStat.DataTextField = "Descrip";`

Also, you need to persist the Selected item between post-backs (for example, in Session Variable) and then show it selected after binding. Otherwise, you can implement partial/conditional web page rendering via Microsoft AJAX (use UpdatePanel and specify Dropdown Trigger events).

There are more efficient solutions (for example, to store the content of data fields in a List or Array, or Dictionary and bind Dropdown control to that data structure, as described in the article: [Binding-ASP-NET-DropDownList](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214418/Binding-ASP-NET-DropDownList-to-Array-Dictionary-a)), but it requires substantial code modification.

Also, this task can be accomplished by using Javascript code snippets on HTML Select element rendered by ASP.NET Drop-down control, but that solution won't work if Javascript is disabled on the client's computer.

Hope this may help.
Best regards,

Comment: Why couldn't you do this with JavaScript?

Comment: @Greg: Sure thing it can be done via Javascript, but: 1). Javascript could be disabled on the client machine; 2). it's not included in the tags list as a possible solution. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Except if you're using web forms you'll have to use postbacks, which would cause the entire page to re-render.

Comment: @Greg: apparently, you can extend the solution by using Microsoft AJAX to implement partial page rendering. Regards,

Comment: But why implement an Update Panel, when you could simply call a web-service or just as simple as do JavaScript.  I'm not saying your approach is wrong, nor incorrect, it just seems like overkill for an incredibly simple issue.  Especially since the value will only be the id, vs the text.

Comment: @Greg: I guess the question is already answered; there is no need for extended discussion. User may apply any solution from the variety provided in your and my answers. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

I would personally do this via JavaScript, a jQuery sample:

```
$('#<%= Sample.ClientId %>').blur(function () {
     var content = $('#<%= Sample.ClientId %> > option:selected').text().split('|');
      $('#<%= Sample.ClientId %> > option:selected').text(content)
});
```

This would be a simple approach, otherwise you'll need to anchor onto a Postback.  Then wrap in an Update Panel or do some form of Ajax to handle via Server Side.

Comment: I am using some update panels so may just try that. I was thinking that approach but was thinking if there was another way.